# how to call a specific function from a hub using signalR

Tags: signalr

I am attempting to call different javascript functions (from the server to the client!) based on what parameters the server has received.

How can I specify which function with which parameter I would like to invoke on the clientside from the server?

```
public class TestData
{
    public string function{ get; set; }
    public string element{ get; set; }
}

public class PerfHub : Hub
{       
    public void Send(string id, string message)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            List<TestData> testList = new List<TestData>();
            if (id == "1")
            {
                testList.Add(new TestData { function= "show", element= "grid" });
                Clients.All.sendInstructions(id, testList);
            }
            else if (id == "2")
            {
                testList.Add(new TestData { function= "hide", element= "grid" });
                Clients.All.sendInstructions(id, testList);
            }
```

My JavaScript on a client looks like this:

```
 $(function () {

    var instructions = $.connection.perfHub;

    // receive instructions from the server
    instructions.client.sendInstructions = function (id, message) {


        var requestedFunction = message;

        function show(parameters) {
            $(parameters).show();
        }

        show();

        function hide(parameters) {
            $(parameters).show();
        }

        hide();
```

Currently I send the id to the server using jQuery .hover method as I can't seem to get click event to work properly.

```
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $('html *').hover(function () {
            // Call the Send method on the hub.
            instructions.server.send($(this).attr('id'), $(this).val());
            //$('#message').val($(this).attr('id')).focus();
        }, function () {
            $('#message').val('').focus();
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: what's the error you get? what actually happens? Clients.All.sendInstructions(id, testList); is the correct way to call a function called sendInstructions on the client

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it using dynamic keys.

```
var instructions = $.connection.perfHub;

    instructions.client.sendInstructions = function (id, message) {

        if (id === "serverFunction") {

            var ctx = {
                showRoads: function (param) { $(param).show(); },
                hideRoads: function (param) { $(param).hide(); },
                shoresOn: function (param) { $(param).show(); },
                shoresOff: function (param) { $(param).hide(); },
                showTiles: function (param) { $(param).show(); },
                sideTiles: function (param) { $(param).hide(); }
            }

            for (var index = 0; index < message.length; ++index) {
                ctx[message[index].function](message[index].element);
            }

        }
    }

    // Call the Send method on the hub.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $('html *').click(function () {
            instructions.server.send($(this).attr('id'), $(this).val());
        });
    });
```

Hope this comes in useful for people, it definitely did for me :)